# Node JS Visitors Mongoose Schema, count visits by years, months, weeks, days

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi this is a Schema to count the amount of visitors to my sites, i have multiple domains.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const VisitorSchema = Schema({
    domain: String,
    count: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Visitor', VisitorSchema);
```

I would like to save in mongoDB the amount of visitors to my sites in periods of time. At this point i can increase the 'count' property but what if i want to organize by years, months and weeks.

```
async function saveVisitor(domain){
    let visitors = await Visitor.findOne({domain});
    if(visitors == null) {
        const startCount = new Visitor({
            domain: domain,
            count: 1
        });
        startCount.save();
    } else {
        visitors.count++;
        visitors.save();
    }
}
```

So my question is: how can i create the years as dynamic properties in mongoose?. What i have in mind is to start counting from a firstVisitDate property. Thanks in advance.

```
{ 
    domain: String,
    firstVisitDate: Date,
    2022: {
        today: Number,
        week: Number,
        month: Number,
        year: Number
    },
    2023: {
        today: Number,
        week: Number,
        month: Number,
        year: Number,
    }
    total: Number
}
```

Comment: better approach will be keep visitors by day and then use aggregate to get desired output

Comment: @undefined_variable how can i use aggregate in this case? can you give me an example please?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ along with count will help

Comment: Is the entry `{2022: {today: ...}}` meant to contain the number of visits today? So must it be reset to zero every midnight?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can use node-cron to automatize jobs and reset visitors counter every midnight: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

```js
const nodeCron = require('node-cron');

const cron = {
    run: function() {
        nodeCron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
            updateVisitorDateCounter();
        })
    } 
};
cron.run(); // run every midnight
```

updateVisitorDateCounter function:

```js
async function updateVisitorDateCounter() {
    const date = new Date();

    if(date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() != 0) return;// prevent restart 'today' counter if server restarts (only works with same time setted in cron)
    const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    const dayName = days[date.getDay()];
    const monthName = months[date.getMonth()];
    
    const domainVisitors = await Visitor.find();

    for(let visitor of domainVisitors) {
        visitor.today = 0;
        const visitorUpdated = await visitor.save();
    }
    
    const newWeek = dayName === 'Sunday' ? true : false;
    if(newWeek) {
        for(let visitor of domainVisitors) {
            visitor.week = 0;
            const visitorUpdated = await visitor.save();
        }
    }

    const newMonth = date.getDate() === 1 ? true : false;   //first day of month
    if(newMonth) {
        for(let visitor of domainVisitors) {    
            if(visitor.history.length == 0) {
                visitor.history = [{ year: date.getFullYear(), months: [{name: monthName, counter: visitor.month}] }]
            } else {
                let historyMonths = visitor.history.find(x => x.year === date.getFullYear()).months;
                historyMonths.push({name: monthName, counter: visitor.month});
                visitor.history = [{ year: date.getFullYear(), months: historyMonths }];
            }
            visitor.month = 0;
            const visitorUpdated = await visitor.save();
        }
    }

    const newYear = date.getMonth() === 0 && date.getDate() === 1 ? true : false;
    if(newYear) {
        // code here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way is not good and have some problem like what if you want to add more step organization like visitor of 2 months or something like that.
instead of adding a number into your counter create an array of visits and add timestamp to it each time a user visit your site.
by this way you can easily query visitor for each period time you want also you can create a graph by time of your visitor visit site. you can expand this and by saving timestamp with user id you can know what user what time visit your site or something like that.

Comment: whit this approach you can get all visited by length of your array too without any complex query

Comment: I don't like the idea of store all Dates for each request, for a light DB collection i would like to just store the counts. In case i would like to get the amount of 2 or more months, you are right, a solution could be for example 2022: { month: {jan: Number, feb: Number}}